# javascript 2d array bug

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, undefined

i have the following object:

```
var tiles = {
 setupTiles : function() {
 this.board = [];
 for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  this.board[i] = [];
 }
 for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   for(var j = 0; j < 21; j++) {
     if(j == 20) {
       tiles.board[i][j] = new tile("#000099", true);
     } else {
       tiles.board[i][j] = new tile("#000099", false);
     }
   }
 }
}
```

and i create the 2d array in a call:

```
tiles.setupTiles();
```

then i let my program run for a short while until a certain state and then call:

```
function paintAll() {
 for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  for(var j = 0; j < 21; i++) {
   console.log(tiles.board[i][j]);
   ctx.fillStyle = tiles.board[i][j].color;
   ctx.fillRect(i*30, j*30, 30, 30);
  }
 }
}
```

but every 11th call to tiles.board[i][j] results in

```
TypeError: tiles.board[i] is undefined.
```

Note that before this function call i havent changed anything in tiles.board

any help would be great!

Comment: Vote to close as caused by a simple typo (`i++` should be `j++`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for(var j = 0; j < 21; i++) {`

In this line you are incrementing `i`, not `j`

Correct code would be:
`for(var j = 0; j < 21; j++) {`